# Insert multiple records to database using MS Access 2007

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual Basic (VB 2010).
How do I insert multiple records to the database using MS Access 2007? My code is not working:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        If DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox("Belum ada transaksi", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Informasi")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox6.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Jumlah bayar belum diinput!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Informasi")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        If RadioButton1.Checked Then
            For baris As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
                Dim simpan As String = "Insert into TBL_JUALTUNAI (NomorFaktur,TglTransaksi,WaktuTransaksi,KodeBarang,NamaBarang,HargaSatuan,JumlahBeli,Total) values " & _
        "('" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value & "')"
                CMD = New OleDbCommand(simpan, CONN)
                CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next baris
        End If

        If RadioButton2.Checked Then
            Dim simpan1 As String = "Insert into TBL_PELANGGAN (NomorFaktur,TglTransaksi,WaktuTransaksi,NamaPelanggan,AlamatPelanggan,TelpPelanggan,KodeBarang,NamaBarang,HargaSatuan,JumlahBeli,Total) values " & _
"('" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(8).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(9).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(4).Value & "')"
            CMD = New OleDbCommand(simpan1, CONN)
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If

        CMD = New OleDbCommand("select * from TBL_BARANG where KodeBarang='" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value & "'", CONN)
        RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
        RD.Read()
        If RD.HasRows Then
            Dim kurangistok As String = "update TBL_BARANG set StockBarang= '" & RD.Item(4) - DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value & "' where KodeBarang='" & DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value & "'"
            CMD = New OleDbCommand(kurangistok, CONN)
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: In what way does this code fail?  It looks like you're executing `INSERT` statements, isn't that what you wanted to do?

Comment: thanks for reply sir, only one record insert to database on datagridview, not multiple record....

Comment: When you step through this in the debugger, where does the behavior differ from what you expect?  You have some conditionals and loops, perhaps the state of the variables isn't what you assume it to be.  When you check, what happens?

Comment: like i tell before, i have multiple record on my datagridview, but when i hit button4 always only one record on row 1 have to insert to my database table....but i have multiple record on datagridview, not like my assume...all record will insert to my table...

Comment: If at any point you want to debug this and provide helpful information to solve the problem, you are encouraged to return here and post that information.  But nobody here can debug this on your computer for you.

Comment: thanks sir...i will check again...

Comment: The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate 

values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and 

try again. <-- error like this now...

Comment: Which line throws that error and what data are you inserting?  *Specifically* what values when debugging, not just what you assume should be there?

Answer (score 0):

With that code, you aren't going to insert multiple records at once. Each `INSERT` command will only insert one row, so you have to use multiple `INSERT` commands for multiple rows.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a `DataGridView` where there multiple rows, and you want to insert the selected rows, yes? 
Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you should be doing is enumerating through the DataGridView's rows and insert a row to the database for each row in that DataGridView?

In that case, use a `For Each` loop to retrieve the rows (`DataGridView1.Rows`) and then execute your `INSERT` command in that loop.

**Edit: In reply to your comment, I don't know the full context of your code, but I can get you started.**

```
    For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        Dim myCommand As String = "INSERT INTO " 'From here, insert your parameters for that row. You can call on dgvRow.Cells.
        CMD = New OleDbCommand(myCommand, CONN)
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir, correctly, im going to insert multiple records at once, and going to insert  (all record, maybe more than 5 record) on selected rows...can you write example basically from my code ? thanks before...

Comment: Sure, I've just edited the post so you can use that to get started.

Comment: thanks sir i will try your sugesstion, later i will post my full content here, many thanks...

Comment: Don't worry about posting full code, I'm not going to provide full code for you, you have to learn too.

Comment: sir still don't work now the error is The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate 

values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that 

contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and 

try again.

Comment: I'm not sure of what context your error is occurring. Can you post some code and tell me where it's occurring?

Comment: can i send u an email sir...plss